# How do you implement inference with extensions <java>

Tags: java, extends, inference

I was trying to figure out how to do simple implementations and I thought, what if the interface extends to another interface?
so for example,

```
public interface A{
    public void a();
}

public interface B{
    public void b();
}

public interface C extends B, A {
    public void c();
}
```

If I was to implement interface C on another class what do I have to do?
I tried this from reading other threads:

```
public class Example<E extends B&A> implements C{
    public void c(){
    }
}
```

Which doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: "inference with extensions"? What is meant by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats wrong with ... simply implementing all interfaces?

```
public class Example implements C {
  @Override 
  public void a(){ }
  @Override 
  public void b(){ }
  @Override 
  public void c(){ }
}
```

In other words: what do you think to gain from making Example a generic type in the first place?!

Meaning: if there is a deeper problem that I don't see - you should consider updating your question and explain what you intend to do (to avoid solving a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here). If there is no deeper problem, go with the most simple solution (like the one shown above).

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `Example` class to implement `C`... all you need to do is to say `implements C`. The type variable is quite separate and irrelevant to this:

```
public class Example implements C { ... }
```

But looking at your class signature:

```
public class Example<E extends B&A> implements C
```

`E` is a type variable which allows you to handle references to classes implementing both `B` and `A` (but not `C`).

For example, if there is a method in `Example` taking an `E` as a parameter:

```
void someMethod(E e)
```

then you can have the following in its body:

```
void someMethod(E e) {
  e.a();  // OK.
  e.b();  // OK.
  // e.c();  // Compiler error, E doesn't implement C.
}
```